# Retrieve current post's tags

Tags: functions

Is it possible to use get_post() to retrieve which tags were selected in the post?

I would like a way to store a single post's tags into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $tags = get_the_tags($post_id); ?>
```

Here `$post_id` is the ID of the post of which you want to get tags. This is same parameter as passed to `get_post()`. When used inside the loop $post_id is optional & default to the current post.